# Не работает модуль,скажите почему?

Tags: javascript, импорт, export, модули

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Module</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="module">
  import {sayHi} from './say.js';

  document.body.innerHTML = sayHi('John');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
export function sayHi(user) {
  return `Hello, ${user}!`;
}
```

**НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**

Comment: Проверил у себя: все работает

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что браузер не поддерживает модули, и не может загрузить ```./say.js```. Попытайтесь собрать это с помощью ```webpack```

Comment: Походу это реально проблема в браузере

Comment: в каком браузере пробовал? Как именно запускал?

Comment: Chrome, запускал как написано выше